# png shows up in browser but not email clients

Tags: email, png, rgb, adobe-illustrator

This is a strange problem, one that I haven't encountered before.  I've created a header img for an email template in AI and exported it as a RGB png-8.  When I view the template in a browser, it and all other images in the email show up fine.  But when I send the email to my outlook, the header that I created doesn't show up, even though all other images (also png-8s) do.  I've checked the color profiles for the new image against the other images, and they are the same.

Has anyone else ever encountered this problem?  Any experts on saving ping files for web from AI out there?

Comment: Do you really expect someone to guess your problem from your description? I cannot imagine...

Comment: Fair enough.  What other information would be helpful?  I can list the entire color profile for the image, and spell out exactly how I exported the image.  I guess I'm just trying to get a sense of how rare or not rare this issue is.  I can't imagine why it's not working in an email client, so I have a murky sense the problem, myself.  Thanks for prompting me for a better explanation, @leonbloy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.  Strange cache issue - images residing on different servers.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your image is in RGB not in CMYK.